# How To Submit A Web Form Using Robobrowser Or Request

Tags: python, python-requests, robobrowser

Im no Python expert but find it extremely useful in many areas. I have been having issues with getting started with Robobrowser and Requests on two separate occasions in context of submitting a form and retrieving the output. What I want to do; submit travel dates to westjet.com using a web inspector I see "origin-event" and "destination-event" I need to submit the airport codes in my case YYZ and POP and dates. Can someone please help me make sense of these libraries so I know how to accomplish this along with a  proper explanation, thank you.

```
import requests


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Safari 9.0'}
print("Please Print Your Intended Departure Date")
#departure_date = input()

print("Please Print Your Intended Return Date")
#return_date = input()


#
# FLIGHTS ONLY
#

westjetF = "https://www.westjet.com/en-ca/index"
airtransatF = "http://www.airtransat.com/en-CA/home"
sunwingF = "http://www.sunwing.ca"
hotwireF = "https://www.hotwire.com"

#
# VACATIONS ONLY
#
westjetV = "https://www.westjet.com/en-ca/index"
airtransatV = "https://www.transat.com/en-CA/?ici=homepage&icn=moteur_forfait&_ga=1.139381168.282228778.1458947467&search=package&origin=YOW"
airtransatV = "http://www.airtransat.com/en-CA/home"
sunwingV = "http://www.sunwing.ca"




# Payload for Westjet.com yy/mm/dd 00-00-00
Flight_data = {

  'orgin-event': 'POP',
  'destination-event' : 'YYZ',
  'depart' : '2017-04-22' ,
  'return': '2017-04-24',
 # 'numAdults' : '1',
 # 'numChildren': '0',
  #'numInfants': '0',
  #'promoCode': ''
}


with requests.Session() as s:

  execute = s.post(westjetF,data=Flight_data)

print(execute.text)









status = execute.status_code


if(status == 200):
 print("great, Request was processed")
else:
  print("Sorry That Request Wasnt Processed")
```

Comment: `requests.post(url, data=data)` where `data` is a dictionary of input names and input values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , here is how to post with `requests`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  ## for html parsing ##

url = 'http://www.westjet.com'  ## the page you want to GET or POST ##  

## Now get the input names ( with web inspector ) ##
## and make a dictionary with the inputs and data you wand to post ##
post_data = { 'name1' : 'value1', 'name2' : 'value2', etc }

req = requests.post(url, data=post_data)  ## post your data to the page ##
# req = requests.get(url, params=post_data)  ## use this method if you want to GET the page ##

status = req.status_code  ## this is the HTTP response status, eg 200 ##
html = req.text  ## this is the response content ( html ) ##

## Next , you can process your html with BeautifulSoup ## 
## or you can skip this part if you dont care about it ##
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") 
table = soup.find('table')  ## This will find the first table , for example ##
```

Of course that 's a very basic example , there are many more things you can do .
I hope this helps a little bit

Comment: so your post data 'name1' is the var found with the web inspector  so in my case name1 would be replaced with 'orgin-data' and the value1 in your example would be replaced with the input I give python so the airport code? this was the area that was confusing me the most and prompted me to ask a question

Comment: That is correct , you need to make a dictionary with the input name as key and your data as value , eg : { 'orgin-data' : 'your data' } .  Keep in mind that  you should include all inputs in the form .  Also take note of the form 'action' , sometimes it's 'get' , in which case you should send a get request : `requests.get(url, params=post_data)`

Comment: Gave you the answer, thanks for your input; will attempt to create something tonight if I have some issues with my final code I'm going to post it here hopefully no-one minds

Comment: I actually Just posted I thought I had it but the issue keeps returning as I read the html.. The request is fine returns 200 but the issue is this web form. The values are correct if you use firebug you'll see id = "orgin event" which we can safely assume the rest I put ^ follows the same logic. I don't understand whats going on am I doing this wrong? should i be paying attention to the network submission when making the requests what vars are being passed?

Comment: There is no issue with your code , in fact it looks quite fine , however there are a couple of issues with the website .  1) It uses js to display the form , and `requests` or `robobrowser` can't process js - you 'ii have to use `selenium` for that .  2) If you inspect the 'form' tag , you 'll see it gets posted to '[https://www.westjet.com/mobilebook/booking/Booking.html](https://www.westjet.com/mobilebook/booking/Booking.html)' , you could try submitting your data to that page .  I 'll give it a try  and if i make it i 'll post an answer

Comment: ok, great thank you. I knew there was something a little weird going on.

Comment: Im actually going to create another question; Don't want to make the admins angry posting a question in another question. But you do deserve the correct answer and I asked " request or Robo " which you clarified for me and technically will accomplish the task; just not with JS